# Actual permission and owner is not print

Tags: php

I am coding PHP file manager on my local server.
 Problem is when I go parent dir and sub dir, PHP dosen't print actual permission and owner.

Server : Apache2

PHP version : 7.3.14

I go parent dir by clicking "..".

Please help me. Here is my code.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Permission</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php
    $cwd = getcwd();

    if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
        $cwd = $_GET['dir'];
    }

    $fil = scandir($cwd);

    foreach ($fil as $file) {
        $path = realpath($file);
        echo '<tr>';
        if(is_dir($file)) {
            echo '<td><a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?dir='.$path.' ">'.$file.'</a></td>';
            echo '<td>'.posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file))[name].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -3).'</td>';
        }

        else {
            echo '<td><a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?edi='.$path.' ">'.$file.'</a></td>';
            echo '<td>'.posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file))[name].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -3).'</td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The Apache user might not have permission to read the parent directory. You'll need to make sure that the user Apache uses has directory read and execute permissions. The Apache user is typically www-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been meaning to add this very sort of thing to my site editing capabilities.  I'm glad you got it started for me.  The following works as intended:

```
echo '
<table width=50%>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width=60%><p>Name</p></th>
            <th width=20%><p>Owner</p></th>
            <th width=20%><p>Permission</p></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
';

    $cwd = getcwd();

    if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
        $cwd = $_GET['dir'];
    }

    $fil = scandir($cwd);

    foreach ($fil as $file) {
        $path = realpath($file);
        $dir = '/'.$file;
        echo '<tr>';
        if($file == '..'){
            $parent = dirname($cwd);
            echo '<td><a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?dir='.$parent.' ">'.$file.'</a></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.posix_getpwuid(fileowner($file))["name"].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -3).'</p></td>';
        }
        elseif($file == '.') {
            //do nothing
        }
        elseif(is_dir($cwd.'/'.$file)) {
            echo '<td><a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?dir='.$cwd.'/'.$file.' ">'.$cwd.'/'.$file.'</a></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.posix_getpwuid(fileowner($cwd.'/'.$file))["name"].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($cwd.'/'.$file)), -3).'</p></td>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<td><a href=" '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?edi='.$cwd.'/'.$file.' ">'.$file.'</a></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.posix_getpwuid(fileowner($cwd.'/'.$file))["name"].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td><p>'.substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($cwd.'/'.$file)), -3).'</p></td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
    }
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Naturally, you need to make sure that you have a permission system so that only you can access this page.  Let me know if you want an example of that.

Comment: Thank a lot. It wok.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache user might not have permission to read the parent directory. You'll need to make sure that the user Apache uses has directory read and execute permissions. The Apache user is typically www-data.

Be careful: you don't want to give users access to files or directories they shouldn't see!

You could change the group of the directory with:

`chgrp www-data <directory_name>`